# Is there an Xpadder equivalent?

Tags: software-recommendation, mouse, accessibility, gamepad

[Xpadder](http://www.xpadder.com/) allows to control the mouse cursor by using a joystick,gamepad,etc.
Xpadder only works on Windows, however I'm not sure if it would work on Ubuntu too, I'm using a XBOX360 Wireless Controller with Xpadder on Windows.

Could Xpadder Work on Ubuntu too?

Comment: I don't know if this project is still usable, check it: http://freshmeat.net/projects/js2mouse/ , also some feedback which tried it on Ubuntu: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-92564.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty close to Xpadder for linux...

http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/#introduction

And another...

http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/jstest-gtk/

Comment: yeah,not Xpadder but close enough